# Отсутствует перевод описания знака "Ревизор" (Steward)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

В уведомлении

> Вы получили знак «Ревизор» (Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded multiple times per review type) за проверку очереди «Вопросы на закрытие».

не переведено описание знака.

[image: скриншот]

Кстати, в самом [описании знака](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward) первое из этих двух предложений тоже не переведено. К тому же, запись про многократное получение повторяется на двух языках.

> Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded multiple times per review type. Знак можно получать многократно.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15837

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.1.29.38441

По поводу повторения на двух языках, то это не совсем повторение. Вот, например, на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/185/steward):

> Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded multiple times per review type. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Одно предложение говорит о том, что знак можно получать многократно внутри каждой очередь. А последнее - о том, что многократно вообще (по сайту). Раньше это было чуть более осмысленно, т.к. для каждой очереди получалось только по одному разу, а теперь, конечно, выглядит странно. В любом случае - это уже надо править глобально, а не на уровне ruSO.

Оформил запрос на удаление последнего предложения: [Steward badge description rephasing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360294/339911)